# extracting data from dump files

Tags: dumping

I have used Frida and Fridump for Memory Dump & Strings Dump on a mobile device so ,now I have about 500 Files with dump.data format.

> first, I want to extract any pdf files and save them in my pc

> second , I want to look for any text

can somebody help , thanks.

Comment: Unless the PDF file(s) have been mapped to memory you won't find them in the dump. If they were just loaded then you may only find the in-memory representation of a loaded PDF file which has nothing to do with the PDF file and it's structure. Therefore I would instead try to figure out what parts of the app load the PDF files and hooke them to get the path or to understand how and from where the files are loaded so you can dump the original PDF data and save it to a file.

Comment: Thanks @Robert , I'm not an expert ,so how can I understand from where they are loaded. are these dump.data useless, how can I open them or search in them?

Comment: You can try to apply photorec on every dump file. It is a file carver so if there are pdf files in that memory dump it will find them (and a lot of other file formats as well).